# GDAL Georefencer plugin is not displayed in plugins

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-plugins, installation, georeferencing

When searching for the GDAL Georeferencer, it simply doesn't show, I've tried installing/uninstalling and looking for many answers online but couldn't find anything helpful.

I've only ever used this plugin on the school computers, never tried on my own laptop.
(I'm using version 3.28.2 "Firenze")

Comment: The same problem for the same version